# stream response from nodejs request to s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, requestjs

How do you use [request](https://github.com/request/request) to download contents of a file and directly stream it up to s3 using the aws-sdk for node?

The code below gives me `Object #<Request> has no method 'read'` which makes it seem like request does not return a readable stream...

```
var req = require('request');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: myBucket, Key: s3Key}});
var imageStream = req.get(url)
    .on('response', function (response) {
      if (200 == response.statusCode) {
        //imageStream should be read()able by now right?
        s3.upload({Body: imageStream, ACL: "public-read", CacheControl: 5184000}, function (err, data) {  //2 months
          console.log(err,data);
        });
      }
    });
});
```

Per the [aws-sdk docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) `Body` needs to be a `ReadableStream` object.

What am I doing wrong here?

This can be pulled off using the [s3-upload-stream](https://github.com/nathanpeck/s3-upload-stream) module, however I'd prefer to limit my dependencies.

Comment: Where/how is `req` defined?

Comment: @mscdex question updated to reflect req

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use the `response` object if you're manually listening for the response stream:

```
var req = require('request');
var s3 = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: myBucket, Key: s3Key}});
var imageStream = req.get(url)
    .on('response', function (response) {
      if (200 == response.statusCode) {
        s3.upload({Body: response, ACL: "public-read", CacheControl: 5184000}, function (err, data) {  //2 months
          console.log(err,data);
        });
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks!  For others refrence, request's documented way of getting stream is a bit misleading https://github.com/request/request/issues/931

Comment: I'm having this same problem -- this answer is helpful but the file on s3 ends up being zero bytes. Piping the same request to disk results in a valid file.

Comment: @JoshSantangelo if you're still having that problem, maybe have a look at my alternate solution.

Comment: @JoshSantangelo Probably too late, but it might be that you are using the wrong encoding. Request assumes text data if you do not provide encoding, e.g. image data will be corrupted. Use req.get({ url: url, encoding: null }). Zero bytes seem weird though.

Comment: Any ideas how to specify the name the file is stores as?

Comment: @Chet, I think that's the `s3Key` you enter in the `params` object

Answer (score 12):

Since I had the same problem as @JoshSantangelo (zero byte files on S3) with request@2.60.0 and aws-sdk@2.1.43, let me add an alternative solution using Node's own `http` module (caveat: simplified code from a real life project and not tested separately):

```js
var http = require('http');

function copyToS3(url, key, callback) {
    http.get(url, function onResponse(res) {
        if (res.statusCode >= 300) {
            return callback(new Error('error ' + res.statusCode + ' retrieving ' + url));
        }
        s3.upload({Key: key, Body: res}, callback);
    })
    .on('error', function onError(err) {
        return callback(err);
    });
}
```

As far as I can tell, the problem is that `request` does not fully support the current Node streams API, while `aws-sdk` depends on it.

References:

- [request issue about the `readable` event not working right](https://github.com/request/request/issues/919)
- [generic issue for "new streams" support in request](https://github.com/request/request/issues/1402)
- [usage of the `readable` event in aws-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/18c1bd1e5d0a6a23c06afbcd7bb2bf94c6b09e07/lib/s3/managed_upload.js#L164)

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This worked -- but I had to use https instead of http

Comment: A simple switch for https:

var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
            if (url.toString().indexOf("https") === 0){
                http = https;
            }

Answer (score 2):

As `Request` has been deprecated, here's a solution utilizing Axios

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const axios = require('axios');

const downloadAndUpload = async function(url, fileName) {
  const res = await axios({ url, method: 'GET', responseType: 'stream' });
  const s3 = new AWS.S3(); //Assumes AWS credentials in env vars or AWS config file
  const params = {
    Bucket: IMAGE_BUCKET, 
    Key: fileName,
    Body: res.data,
    ContentType: res.headers['content-type'],
  };
  return s3.upload(params).promise();
}
```

Note, that the current version of the AWS SDK doesn't throw an exception if the AWS credentials are wrong or missing - the promise simply never resolves.

Comment: I am trying something very similar to this but this is running inside a test file (jest). So code block is enclosed within a `await expect(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {`. I am enclosing your code inside an async function like so `const resp = async (url) => {` and then calling `resp`. The issue is that I end up getting a time-out. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I have noticed, that the AWS sdk doesn't throw an error if the credentials are missing or don't work - it just never responds, so maybe check that first.

Comment: +1 This was the issue for me as well. I wish I had known this before banging my head for days and trying different ways to fix this. Thanks @skoll